# CentOS7 change in visudo not accepted

Tags: linux, centos, sudo

This is my sudoers file. I am accessing it using sudo visudo. I have added this new user '**user**' then logout/login back to the system but this user still need a password to run sudo commands.

```
## Next comes the main part: which users can run what software on
## which machines (the sudoers file can be shared between multiple
## systems).
## Syntax:
##
##      user    MACHINE=COMMANDS
##
## The COMMANDS section may have other options added to it.
##
## Allow root to run any commands anywhere
root    ALL=(ALL)       ALL
user    ALL=(ALL)       NOPASSWD: ALL

## Allows members of the 'sys' group to run networking, software,
## service management apps and more.
# %sys ALL = NETWORKING, SOFTWARE, SERVICES, STORAGE, DELEGATING, PROCESSES, LOCATE, DRIVERS

## Allows people in group wheel to run all commands
%wheel  ALL=(ALL)       ALL

## Same thing without a password
# %wheel        ALL=(ALL)       NOPASSWD: ALL

## Allows members of the users group to mount and unmount the
## cdrom as root
# %users  ALL=/sbin/mount /mnt/cdrom, /sbin/umount /mnt/cdrom

## Allows members of the users group to shutdown this system
# %users  localhost=/sbin/shutdown -h now

## Read drop-in files from /etc/sudoers.d (the # here does not mean a comment)
#includedir /etc/sudoers.d
```

Comment: Is "user" by any chance member of the wheel group?

Comment: @Darius Yes, it is member of wheel group.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Due to the construct and order of your visudo file, and as you confirmed that user is member of "wheel" group - the visudo files applies the last applicable permission.

So you set user to have no password.

But then the wheel group (where user is a member of) - requires password. This setting wins as this is set AFTER you tell user to use no password.

If you want user to have no password to run sudo:

- Put `user    ALL=(ALL)       NOPASSWD: ALL` below this line `%wheel  ALL=(ALL)       ALL` or
- Remove user from the "wheel" group.